# JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) returning an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` returns an error: "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0".

I suspect `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` returns an error because `JSON.parse()` ends before `JSON.stringify(data)`. I tried to run the code on another file and it worked, so I really don't know how to solve it.

I tried promises and whiles between the acts.

```
getDataInArray = databaseData => {
    console.log(databaseData);

    let json = JSON.stringify(databaseData);
    console.log(json);

    let array = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(array);

    return array;
};
```

The expected type of result from `getDataInArray`: array.
The result: error (Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0)

Comment: What's an example of the data? And which line does the error occur on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unexpected `u` is the `u` of `undefined`. Check the value of `databaseData` because it's probably empty.

Comment: That's the thing - it is not

Comment: What's the value of `databaseData` and `json` when you have an error then ? because it's not a valid JSON format for sure, and we won't be able to help you further without knowing why it's not a valid JSON format.

Comment: You were right. It was a wrong database pull.